# How do I create a username and password with Active Directory in Azure for my website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I want to create a way for someone who visits my site (hosted in Azure), to be blocked by a page that asks for a username and password that I can distribute. Once entered they will see my site! Is this done with Azure Active Directory? If yes, can anyone point me to a tutorial, I can't seem to find anything useful.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You could refer to this article about [enable a web application to authenticate with accounts using Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-tutorials-web-app).

Comment: is this what I need I'm a real newbie to website and azure stuff?

Comment: Before that, you need to [create and Azure AD tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

App Service allows us to use different authentication providers, Azure Active Directory,Facebook,Google,Microsoft,Twitter.

We could enable the **Authentication/Authorization** on from Azure portal. For more information, please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication) tutorial.

[image]